# Get trough SteamDB's browser check

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, steam

I need to get through SteamDB's browser check in my bot, so I could go directly to search results on SteamDB. Is there any way to do it?
Code:

```
async def steam(ctx, *, search):
    await ctx.send('**Шукаю...**')
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
    search = search.replace(" ", "+")
    res = requests.get(
        f'https://steamdb.info/search/?a=app&q={search}&type=1&category=0', headers=headers)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.select('#table-sortable tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) a')[0].getText().strip())

    search = ''
    # print(soup.find_all('a', href=True))
    for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(url['href'])
        if "/app/" in url['href']:
            search = url['href']
            break

    search = 'https://steamdb.info' + search
    res = requests.get(search, headers=headers)
    print(search)

    name = soup.find(itemprop = 'name').getText()
    desc = soup.find(itemprop = 'description').getText()
    reldate = soup.select('table.table.table-bordered tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(2)')[0].getText().strip()
    reldate_mo = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    reldate_mo_t = ['січ', 'лют', 'бер', 'кві', 'тра', 'чер', 'лип', 'сер', 'вер', 'жов', 'лист', 'гру']
    reldate = reldate.split(' –')[0]
    i = 0
    while i < len(reldate_mo):
        if reldate_mo[i] in reldate:
            reldate.replace(reldate_mo[i], reldate_mo_t[i])
            i += 1
```

Error in console, while trying to use command (error on line `print(soup.select('#table-sortable tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) a')[0].getText().strip())`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `soup.select(...)`. The error is saying that you can't access the element at 0 in that iterable.

Comment: @EricJin it prints the empty list and thst's all

Comment: Then you can't access the element at index 0, which explains the error. Do you expect to have stuff in there?

Comment: @EricJin the problem that at first website redirects me to "browser check", then to normal site with search results. But my bot cant get throught this browser check, and i dont know why